# .htaccess: как избавиться от лишних параметров в запросе?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

На сайте [www.stroypanel.ru](http://www.stroypanel.ru) есть раздел **Объекты** *http://www.stroypanel.ru/objects* cо списком объектов, объединенных тегами. Переключаем тег, и нам аяксом подгружается, список объектов этого тега.

Также **id** тега можно поменять в адресной строке через параметр ***?tags***.
Например: *www.stroypanel.ru/objects/?tags=4*. Проблема в том, что таких айдишников можно выбрать сразу несколько, через запятую: *www.stroypanel.ru/objects/?tags=4,5,6* ... и тд.

Поисковики эти адреса индексируют, что в конечном счете может быть чревато многочисленными дублями страницы объектов( если в будущем этих тегов будет 15, 20 и т.д. будет совсем страшно). Поэтому нужно каким-то образом ограничить возможность вписывать в параметр больше одного айдишника. День гугления не дал результатов.

Пытался сконструировать что-то типа этого, но кроме циклического редиректа,я ничего не получил:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tags=(.*[0-9]){1,}(.*)$
  RewriteRule .* http://www.stroypanel.ru/objects$1 [L]
```

Как можно правильно записать то что требуется? Регулярки .htaccess - это моя беда.

Comment: может проще поисковикам запретить индексацию с параметром, чем огород городить?

Comment: И `canonical` можно прописать единый для всех этих страниц.

Comment: Нужно просто чтобы по многим параметрам сразу нельзя было переходить, чтобы они 404 отдавали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/objects\/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tags=(|[^&]*[^\d\&]+[^&]*)(&|$)
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

`?tags=` и `?tags=.` и так далее вызовут 404 ошибку. А `?tags=1` и `?tags=15&page=2` нет.

`[R=404]` с какой версии Apache работает не знаю. На Apache/2.4.10 все ок.

Answer (score 0):

Так проблема не на уровне настройки сервера. Вы никак не ограничите возможность делать запрос к вашему серверу с **любым** URI, вы можете только вернуть ответ с ошибкой или редиректом.

Вам нужно просто указать для поисковиков запрет для таких страниц например через robots.txt

Comment: Это-то в сущности и требуется, если айдишников больше одного - то вернуть 404, а в роботс прописать запрет на добавление вторых айдишников.
Я еще просто хотел убедиться, правильно ли написано условие "если после tags больше одного параметра"

Comment: @АлексейЕрмолаев тогда вам Visman уже написал регулярку